# Avoid use of undefined object in c++

Tags: c++

If I create a class in c++, it is possible to call a function of an object of this class, even if this class does not exists.

For example:

Class:

```
class ExampleClass
{
   private:
       double m_data;

   public:
       void readSomeData(double param)
       {
           m_data = param;
       }
}
```

Any function where this class is used:

```
int main()
{
    ExampleClass* myClass;

    myClass->readSomeData(2.5);
}
```

Ofcourse this wouldn't function, because `myClass` is not defined.
To avoid such situations, I check if `ExampleClass` objects are a `null_ptr`

example:

```
void readSomeData(double param)
{
    if(this == null_ptr)
        return;

    m_data = param;
}
```

But gcc says:

> 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may
>   be assumed to always avaluate to false.

Ofcourse that is only a warning, but I think it is not nice to have this warning. Is there a better way to check if the pointer of a class is defined?

Comment: you are confusing "class" and "instance of that class". That being said, there are many duplicates on this issue. Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined, meaning anything can happen (including it seems to work)

Comment: Deferencing a unitialised pointer invokes undefined behaviour, `this` will never be null in legal code.

Comment: The fact that `this` is a pointer is mostly an oversight; it should've been a reference, and that's how it should be treated (i.e. it's never null). If you get into the function body, you should assume the object has been properly created.

Comment: why do you think the warning is not nice? It is meant to prevent you from writing wrong code

Comment: @user463035818 Why is that code wrong? - It is clear, that it is not possible that `this == null_ptr` in well defined c++ code. But it is possible in not well defined c++ code. Is it wrong to check it?

Comment: your code is wrong because you should never dereference a null pointer and call a method on it. Checking for nullness inside a method gives you the false impression that it would be ok to do so and the warning reminds you that inside a method `this` cannot possibly be null in a correct program

Comment: in different words: its not wrong to check for null inside the method but it doesnt make sense. Checking for null implicitly implies that it would be ok to call a method on a nullpointer, which is defiinitely wrong

Comment: @user463035818 That is interesting. I never thought about that in this way. But I think you are right.

Comment: i am almost never right, but this time yes ;)

Comment: That would mean, that I don't capture that Situation and accept the risk of a runtimeerror?

Comment: It's not your risk. The language flat out forbids calling member functions on invalid object pointers/references. Those who do it are wrong and should fix their code. You are not to blame for programming to the contract that is laid out by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing it in the class is the wrong way, the warning is correct about that if your code is well defined then `this` must not be null, so the test should happen at the time when you call the member function:

```
int main()
{
    ExampleClass* myClass = nullptr; // always initialize a raw pointer to ensure
                                     // that it does not point to a random address

    // ....    

    if (myClass != nullptr) {
      myClass->readSomeData(2.5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If a pointer must not be null at a certain part of your code then you should do it according to [CppCoreGuideline: I.12: Declare a pointer that must not be null as not_null](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i12-declare-a-pointer-that-must-not-be-null-as-not_null)

Micorosoft provides an [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) that has an implementation for `not_null`.

Or if possible then don't use pointers at all but `std::optional`.

So a code setup could look like this:

```
#include <gsl/gsl>

struct ExampleClass {
   void readSomeData(double ){}
};

// now it is clear that myClass must not and can not be null within work_with_class
// it still could hold an invalid pointe, but thats another problem
void work_with_class(gsl::not_null<ExampleClass*> myClass) {
  myClass->readSomeData(2.5);
}

int main()
{
    ExampleClass* myClass = nullptr; // always initialize a raw pointer to ensure
                                     // that it does not point to a random address

    // ....

    work_with_class(myClass);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `nullptr` is only supported since C++11.

Comment: Ok that is the right direction that is what I want to know. If I check at this position, the person, who uses the class have to know, that `myClass` must be checked. The idea was to check it in the member function, to capture errors of users that don't know this.

Comment: Its the same answer I already gave you :) I think the main issue here is your own understanding of C++ classes, where you assume *someone else* could make a mistake, while its the normal every day usage of classes in C++.  As already mentioned in this thread a couple of times, using a non-initialized pointer or dereferencing a null-pointer is wrong usage, and to repeat: you *cannot* catch/avoid this wrong usage *inside* the class implementation.

Comment: @Ahrtaler that's something that should be covered by you tooling. Doing test at parts where the error already happens it the wrong approach. Write your code and use the tooling in a way that it is prevented/minimized. Set the compiler to a hight warning/error level. `pedantic` might be annoying at first, but will really help you at many points to avoid such things, if an external library won't allow  `pedantic` then move that code into a static linked part with lover error warnign settings. And use tools like `clang_tidy` and a Guidelines Support Library.

Comment: I'm not sure C++11 needs to be pointed out anymore, it's 8 years old and C++0x even older. The only reason not to use an up to date compiler is for working on old-very old hardware, something a learner shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is not use pointers at all:

```
int main()
{
    ExampleClass myClass;
    myClass.readSomeData(2.5);
}
```

That way there's no need for any check, and in fact, [checking `this` inside the function is moot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237512/avoid-use-of-undefined-object-in-c/55237555#comment97208124_55237512).

If you need nullability, use `std::optional` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right. But It in some cases it is necessary to use pointer. Not in this example. But in my class it is necessary.

Comment: @Ahrtaler You haven't show an example where it's necessary. I have no idea what else you might have in your code, and so my answer directly answers the question asked.

Comment: @Ahrtaler - If you wrote code the necessitates the check, i.e. you call a member function via an invalid pointer, then your code has a bug! The solution is to fix said bug, not to add this superfluous check.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz pleas don't missunderstand me. It seams like you think I tried to attack you with my answer before. That was not my intention. I am sorry for that if you fealt attacked.

Answer (score 1):

Either don't use pointers as Bartek Banachewicz has pointed out, or properly initialize and check the pointer:

```
int main()
{
    ExampleClass* myClass= 0;

    if (myClass)
       myClass->readSomeData(2.5);

   return 0;
}
```

Of course you still *have to* add the instantiation of the object at some point, otherwise the code is nonsense.

Comment: You don't need that `return 0;`.

Comment: Yes It is always necesarry to initialize a pointer. My question is not how to use a pointer without initialtion. The idea is, that the class could be used by other people. I try to check every  eventuality.

Comment: @ Bartek Banachewicz but it is better to read if there is a `return 0;`

Comment: Using classes in C++ is a concept which can involve proper handling of pointers, which is something you cannot possibly handle in any way in the *implementation* of that class.